# In web.config, A duplicate 'system.web.webPages.razor / host' section is defined

Tags: web-config

I'm trying to run this app
https://github.com/martinokello/EntertainmentTicketMaster

But when I run this app, some errors happen.

---

Module     IIS Web Core

Notification       BeginRequest

Handler    Not yet determined

Error Code     0x800700b7

Configuration error    A duplicate 'system.web.webPages.razor / host' section is defined.

Requested URL      http://localhost:6848/Views/Account/Login.cshtml

Physical Path      F:\code\EntertainmentTicketMaster-

master\EntertainmentTicketMaster\Views\Account\Login.cshtml

Logon Method       Not yet determined

Logon User     Not yet determined

Request tracking directory     C:\Users\young\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\ENTERTAINMENTTICKETMASTER

Configuration Source

```
 5:     <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    6:       <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    7:       <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
```

---

I searched several articles to solve this error, but they didn't work.

Above configuration error says A duplicate 'system.web.webPages.razor / host' section is defined.

And I inspected that.

And this codes which are related to this error are defined in both web.config of root directory and view folder.

```
 5:     <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    6:       <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    7:       <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
```

What causes this error and how can I solve this?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And this codes which are related to this error are defined in both web.config of root directory and view folder.

This is why you receive this error. You should define it only in root directory.